# There is not enough space on http://myCompany.com

Tags: 2010, quota

I am using SP 2010 and try to copy a lot of files to a document library by the file explorer. I got this error:

> There is not enough space on `http://myCompany.co`m. You need an additional 13,4 GB to copy these files

I try to upload only small parts and only the first 3 parts worked. The fourth part give me again the same error but with another gb value:

> There is not enough space on http://myCompany.com. You need an additional 2,4 GB to copy these files

What is going wrong? I do not have a site collection quota!

Here is a print screen of the site collection quota. There is no limit.
[image]

Comment: Check the quota setting for that site collection in Central Admin.

Comment: Dear Amal, see updated printscreen. There is no site collection quota.

Comment: Can you check you SQL drives and see if those has enough space?

Comment: Couple of things to check....How big the file size you trying to upload? what is file upload limit on that web app? check Databas have enough space and also database not caped.

Comment: The file size is 17GB.

Comment: Are any of the files larger then 2GB?

Comment: No, there are no files which are larger than 2GB. I know the limit of 2GB, but if there were files bigger than 2GB I expect another error.

Comment: what is the size of the actual hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

Check How much space is left on the Hard Drive where SP2010 is running. SP expands very rapidly and it could just be that you are running low on space.

Also check your SQL Server Hard Drive if there is enough space. Unless they are on one machine.

Also bare in mind that more space is needed than the size of the files themselves when copying, expecially when the files to be copied are large.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check enough space on your system drive which will be utilized while copying files to site.